# When you set a global configuration option for git on Windows, where does it get written to?

Tags: git, configuration, global, newline

If you set something like this on Windows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Where is this global setting getting written to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will write the values in a file called .gitconfig, unless you specify another name with the '`--file`' option

```
 git config --global --file myFile key value
```

Note: the environment variable `GIT_CONFIG` can also be used to specify another name for this file. `--file` will supersede GIT_CONFIG value.

Whatever its name, it will write it in:

- $HOME for Unix
- %HOMEPATH% for Windows (c:\Users\MyName by default)

If $HOME or %HOMEPATH% is not properly set, the `git config` command will fail.

It is used to store a per-user configuration and serves as fallback values for the repository-local '`.git/config`' file.

Comment: Also with new enough Git you can use "`git config --global --edit`" to open per-user config file in your editor... and from there I would guess you would be able to find where it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can check your $HOME directory for a file like .gitconfig