# git submodule in stage - how to remove?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have some items with "archive" label in my gitlab web interface:

[image]

Problem is what my local repo have real files in this directory:

[image]

I can't push changes from this directory to remote server. I tried to remove yii2-rbac from remote server:

```
git rm --cached path/to/yii2-rbac
```

But it didn't work, after next push, mysterious file with same name 'yii2-rbac' appears again...

How can I fix it?

update: I have taken into account comments and realized what I deal with submodules:

```
git ls-files --stage | grep $160000

160000 3fc4af92c20ca2bf97bf01a50819565b5a6fe621 0   path/to/yii2-migration-utility
160000 c6d315a3c9652b3b1ced19fe105f65e6e09f375b 0   path/to/yii2-rbac
```

One question: how can I delete these submodules and start using path/to/yii2-rbac as usual directory?

Comment: It looks to me like you are working with [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), which is likely the source of your confusion. Even with that though, your question remains unclear: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git commit to common submodule (master branch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590400/git-commit-to-common-submodule-master-branch)

Comment: I need to push local changes into remote repo, but i can't and i don't know why... only this directory after my commits remains untouchable, changes doesn't apply on remote repo... (.gitignore empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution which works for me. In main git repo:

```
rm -rf path/to/child/.git
```

Will remove "submodule" status from directory (but all files still remains). In GitLab interface this directory now looks like common folder:

[image]