# Keeping two Git branches different by one file

Tags: git

I am certain two branches of my Git repo should only ever be different in a single file. The simplest way to ensure this is to do all work in `branch1`, and merge it into `branch2` whenever I switch to it (wrapped into a shell script, so I only need one command per switch). However, is there a way to do this with even less work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use a git **[filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)**, with a smudge script intelligent enough to:

[image]

- recognize it is dealing with that single file (reminder: [such a script only deals with file content, not file*name*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393))
- put the right content depending on the current branch.

But the question is: do you need two branches at all?
If this is a config file, as mentioned in "[Git: how maintain (mostly) parallel branches with only a few difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152841/git-how-maintain-mostly-parallel-branches-with-only-a-few-difference/2153000#2153000)", storing templates might be better. That same question proposes other alternatives.

Comment: +1 Finally, out of all the "duplicate" related posts on this site, @VonC provides the correct way of doing it. Perhaps harder at first, but its not a hack like the rebase methods.