# Which symfony auto-generated files should you avoid editing?

Tags: version-control, symfony1

In the symfony framework, a great many files are auto-generated at various stages of development. Some of these files are meant to be edited and manually-customized while others are meant to never (or very rarely) be hand-edited but instead to change as the result of changes to other configuration or settings files.

Which symfony files fit into this latter category of "avoid hand-editing"? I want to know so I can exclude these files from revision-control. Another reason to know is simply to know which files I should avoid editing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the **[GitHub project `gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore)** has both .gitignore files for [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) or [symfony2](http://symfony-reloaded.org/) projects:

- **[`symfony.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony.gitignore)**:

```
cache/*
log/*
web/uploads/*
config/databases.yml
config/propel.ini
data/sql
lib/filter/doctrine/base/Base*
lib/form/doctrine/base/Base*
lib/model/doctrine/base/Base*
lib/model/om/*
lib/model/map/*
```

- **[symfony2.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony2.gitignore)**:

```
*/logs/*
*/cache/*
web/uploads/*
web/bundles/*
```

That illustrates the [differences and evolutions of the structure of a symfony project](http://docs.symfony-reloaded.org/guides/symfony1.html).

Comment: Note that `databases.yml` and `propel.ini` are excluded because they might contain username/password details, rather than because they shouldn't be edited.

Comment: @Matt: true, so in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132152/when-you-have-secret-key-in-your-project-how-can-pushing-to-github-be-possible/5132569#5132569

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit anything that starts with Auto or Base as these files are recreated when you run various build tasks. Edit the files that extend from these classes instead.