# Open sourcing code without including specific set-up values in source

Tags: git, open-source, config

I am creating a few small experiments / examples which I am open sourcing on git hub.

How have people dealt with user specific config/set-up vars in the past?

I would ideally like to commit the exact same code that I myself am using, but without including my URL's or app id / secrets etc.

I have thought that perhaps I could do it in one of the following ways, but is there a standard or recommended way of doing this?

```
baseURL = include myConfig.txt;
```

or

```
baseURL = "Enter Your URL Here";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the very simplest config options as *environment variables*.

You could have a *small config object*, which holds dummy values.

You could add *a config.ini.sample file*.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of configuration (file with "secret private" content, private as "visible only within *my* working tree, but never versioned in the Git repo), I always recommend a [custom filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132152/when-you-have-secret-key-in-your-project-how-can-pushing-to-github-be-possible/5132569#5132569) (See also [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html#keyword_expansion) for the principle):

[image: filter driver]

- a template of your setting file (`settings.template`, with `baseURL`),
- a script able to generate a proper setting file `settings` based on local values found in your working tree (like an encrypted file with the secret value ready to be decoded and put in the `setting` file by the `smudge` script)

Answer (score 1):

Me personally I would use a special commit to my own GIT tree which includes my own specialities. So they are separated from the rest of the history.
Whenever I push my changes to the public tree, that commit would be omitted.

I don't know however how to ensure not to accidentally push the commit. But there ought to be some way.

Answer (score 0):

You can read configuration values from a file, for example `config.txt`, and commit `config.txt.example` with helpful comments, default values where applicable and dummy values in other places, so users can just copy that to `config.txt` and change the needed values.