# How to create a restricted Git release branch that contains sensitive data?

Tags: git, release, web-deployment, bitbucket, release-management

I have a simple web-store, some php/html/css/js files. The master branch on Bitbucket is actually a development branch, i.e. developers push into it and then I pull the changes to development web-server as Git is installed on my shared hosting and I have SSH access there.

The question is how to create a release branch out of this? I realize that I could just create a release branch and push the changes from master (which is actually development) when it comes to release.

However, the thing is that release web-site code contains production passwords, merchant ids and so on - so I would like to keep all these in secret. And if I create a release branch in the same repository then everyone in my team would see that sensitive data.

So what would be a solution? Please note that I am a git-beginner.

Thank you!

Comment: The first question I would look into is why you need to store this type of sensitive data in version control. I'd consider this a potential design smell. I don't think putting it either in a branch with stricter access controls is going to help much; I'd look to keep the releases in a separate repo and push between the two, but that only partially solved the problem as someone might manage to get access to that repo.

Comment: I totally agree with Timo. This kind of information should be stored separate from your code in some configuration file. Of course it would be possible to version you configuration but this would be more as a secure backup, not accessible for everybody.

Comment: You are totally right gentlemen: I came to the same conclusion after reading a lot of stuff over night. No sensitive data should be stored in repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you can store sensitive information outside of any git repo, then you can register in git repo [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5132569/6309).
That would include:

[image: smudge]

- template files
- a [smudge script](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) registered in a [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) files for those template able to:

  - access the secret values from an outside source
  - generate the actual config files (which are not versioned and remain private to the repo) with the right values in it depending of the current environment