# What is the best way of storing secret data that uses for module tests only?

Tags: django, unit-testing

Because of test db re-creating every time when I start unittests so I can't store access token (secret data) there. Also I can't store token directly in code, because I want to push it to github.
There is some elegant and easy way to save access token once without any additional files?

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132152/when-you-have-secret-key-in-your-project-how-can-pushing-to-github-be-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a .toml file. Then use [pytoml](https://github.com/avakar/pytoml) to parse it.

For example:

```
>>> with open('file.toml', 'rb') as fin:
...     obj = toml.load(fin)
>>> obj
{'secret': 8287474}
```

**Do not** commit this file to github!

Best practices are:

1. Have example.toml file with empty values(This one you can commit)
2. Use test.toml/production.toml/development.toml for different envs
3. Divide it to categories and add comments so new developers will understand.

Comment: Downvoted. This solution does not take care of the security,encryption,public access of the token on github part.

Comment: It is, you just need to commit the example file and not the production one @DhruvPathak

Comment: Can you please give me an example of project (on github) that uses this approach? @Or Duan

Comment: @KhasanKhafizov Flask, a famous web framework talk about it on the docs here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/#configuring-from-files

They use different format but the same approach. 
If the answer helps, please accept it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted wisdom says to store keys (and other config variables) in environment variables, as per the [12factor directives](http://12factor.net/config).

In Django (or Python, for that matter), you can simply read the key in your settings file with

```
import os
...
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
...
```