# git encrypt/decrypt remote repository files while push/pull

Tags: git, encryption

Is it possible to automatically encrypt files via 'git push' before transferring to a remote repository? And automatically decode them while 'git pull'.

I.e, if I have some remote server with shared access with git repository there, and I don't want our project to be stolen without a permission...
Maybe there is some special git-hooks before push and after pull?

Comment: A similar question was asked on the Git mailing list in July 2009:
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/123466/focus=123485

Comment: I alose found a discussion here: https://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/3/13/1153274/thread

Comment: kerneltrap link's dead

Comment: Thanks to the [archive](https://archive.org), the content survives: [kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/3/13/1153274/thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20090131024526/https://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/3/13/1153274/thread)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes and no.

You could try to depend on hook but that supposes they are installed at the remote locations, and that is not always reliable.

Another way to achieve almost the same effect would be by using a **[smudge/clean attribute filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154948/how-can-i-track-system-specific-config-files-in-a-repo-project/2155355#2155355)**, **but not for a full repo**.

[image: smudge/clean]

<sup>(Source: [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/): [Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes))</sup>

That way the smudge script is able decode the files, while the clean script would encode them.
Again, that could work for a few sensitive files, **not for a full repo**.

Off course, those scripts would not be in the repository itself, and would be managed/communicated by another way.

As [Alkaline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1556338/alkaline) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456954/git-encrypt-decrypt-remote-repository-files-while-push-pull/2457006#comment54706421_2457006), that idea does not scale for a repo, as the main git maintainer [Junio C. Hamano comments back in 2009](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/113221):

> As the sole raison d'etre of `diff.textconv` is to allow potentially lossy
>   conversion (e.g. msword-to-text) applied to the preimage and postimage
>   pair of contents (that are supposed to be "clean") before giving a textual
>   diff to human consumption.
>
> The above config may appear to work, but **if you really want an encrypted repository, you should be using an encrypting filesystem.
>
>   That would give an added benefit that the work tree
>   associated with your repository would also be encrypted**.

---

Even though it does not scale to a full repo, the idea was implemented (3 years later in 2013) with **[`git-crypt`](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt)**, as detailed in [Dominic Cerisano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048170/dominic-cerisano)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047100/6309).
`git-crypt` uses a **content filter driver** (implemented in cpp, with [`commands.cpp`](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt/blob/788a6a99f4289745e6bd12fae2ad8014af320a4f/commands.cpp#L149-L168) setting up your `.gitattributes` with the relevant `smudge` and `clean` filter commands).
As any content filter driver, you can then limit the application of `git-crypt` to the set of files you want, in the same `.gitattributes` file:

```
secretfile filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
*.key filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
```

As [mentioned in the `README`](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt/blob/788a6a99f4289745e6bd12fae2ad8014af320a4f/README#L93-L102):

> `git-crypt` relies on git filters, which were not designed with encryption
>   in mind.
>
> As such, `git-crypt` is not the best tool for encrypting most or
>   all of the files in a repository.
>   Where `git-crypt` really shines is where most of your repository is public, but you have a few files (perhaps private keys named `*.key`, or a file with API credentials) which you need to encrypt.
>
> For encrypting an entire repository, consider using a system like **[`git-remote-gcrypt`](https://spwhitton.name/tech/code/git-remote-gcrypt/)** instead.

(see more at  [spwhitton/ tech/ code/ git-remote-gcrypt](https://spwhitton.name/tech/code/git-remote-gcrypt/), from **[Sean Whitton](https://spwhitton.name/)**)

Comment: Very good advice! Thanks.
I think this method is very useful with custom .gitattributes rules!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig

Comment: @Daniel it works with any local repo: the clean script restore the encrypted  version on commit. What is pushed (to, for instance, GitHub) is therefore encrypted.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there's an image missing from the answer. My browser displays "alt text" after "smudge/clean attribute filter driver" above.

Comment: @Daniel I have restored the picture

Comment: Thanks again. Is there any way you could provide code for this method?

Comment: Junio C Amano (the maintainer of the git codebase) has warned against using smudge this way. http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/113221

Comment: @Alkaline Good point. I have made that warning explicit in the answer.

Comment: Note that git-crypt is for selectively encrypting remote assets, not entire repositories. Also note most git service providers (eg. GitHub, BitBucket) do not provide encrypted storage, even on [their](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4FwJdBb6_M&t=3m31s) 'private' repositories. Git-crypt is actual encrypted storage, independent of git service providers.

Comment: Link for `git-remote-gcrypt` has left the house.

Comment: @Chris For an 8-years old answer, I am not surprised. I have updated and documented the link to the new `git-remote-gcrypt`.

Answer (score 12):

You can take a look at this project: https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt

**UPDATE**: This above project is deprecated and recommends using https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt

Comment: Guessing it's because the project says there's some controversy and points to article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/113221

Comment: Limitations: git-crypt does not work reliably with some third-party git GUIs, such as Atlassian SourceTree and GitHub for Mac. Files might be left in an unencrypted state.

Answer (score 8):

### How to secure public and private remote assets using [git-crypt](https://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/).

- Transparent to all git clients and services (eg. GitHub, BitBucket,
  etc).
- Linux, OSX and Windows support.
- **Asset level** encryption (see [VonC's
  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457006/1048170)).
- [**AES-256**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116596/will-quantum-computers-render-aes-obsolete) cipher.

**Create** your 256 bit private key (RETAIN AND PROTECT THIS KEY)

```
sudo apt install git-crypt 
mkdir key; cd key;
git init; git-crypt init
git-crypt export-key ~/crypt.key
```

**Push** a file called `.gitattributes` to each repo's root directory.
It should contain one asset pattern per file, directory or type you wish to encrypt:

```
docs/doc.txt  filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
js/**         filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
*.java        filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
src/cpp/*.h   filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
```

**Encrypt** assets in each repo:

```
cd repo-root-directory
git-crypt unlock ~/crypt.key
git-crypt status -f
Push (from command line or git client)
```

**Continue** your git workflow as usual.

- Run `git-crypt unlock ~/crypt.key` **once** on any new clones of
  these secured repos.
- You may wish to purge old unencrypted commit histories on all branches
  and tags.
- If you use a git client, it must fully support git filters and diffs.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to do this.

One is to use a project like git-crypt, 
http://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/
which adds in fiters to pull and push process, or set up the filters manually as described here
https://gist.github.com/shadowhand/873637

Another way if you are working in a linux environment, is to use ecryptfs. For this scenario, in base of your project directory you could, for example, create two directories

```
project/encrypted_src

project/src
```

Then from the root of the project directory you would mount using the command

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs encrypted_src src
```

entering a pass-phrase and accepting the defaults when prompted. At this point, files placed in src/ will be encrypted into encrypted_src/ on the fly. When you are finished just

```
sudo umount src
```

and only the encrypted files remain. Essentially files are committed and pushed from encrypted_src/ and edited in src.
As long as everyone uses the same pass-phrase (or mounts with the same key) the repo can be shared among developers. Also you can get fancier. You can encrypt file names as well as just file contents, or encrypt different folders in a repo with different pass-phrases or keys. The last feature is nice if you have configuration files with sensitive access information that individual groups (dev, test, production) will want to maintain privately.

That said, though, be aware that once you start encrypting stuff. You loose a lot of the advantages of source control like being able to see diffs between various commits. If you have a project of any size the ability to review commits will be invaluable. If you expect bugs, at some point or another, the ability to analyse and find their point of introduction by back tracking through commit history will also be invaluable. So secure your server first and then use encryption only where in makes sense to protect sensitive info in  source control. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

There are Tahoe-LAFS hooks provided by [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/forum/tips:_special__95__remotes__47__hook_with_tahoe-lafs/), which admittedly might be more complicated than you need.