# Git for project with overlapping public and private portions

Tags: git, version-control, access-control

I'm trying to figure out what the cleanest way is to compose a public repository out of a subset of a private repository (or compose the private as a union with the public portion) and still have the shared files be updated in tandem. As an example, say I have these two files:

- public_file
- private_file

An end user should be able to pull only public_file, but maintainers should be able to modify both public_file and private_file. What git idiom would be suited to this kind of access control layout?

Comment: If you only want maintainers modify files in private repo, they can use `git remote add <URL for private repo>` then commit&push changes. other end users only work for public repo. I'm not sure if it's your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For a single file, you would use a [**`smudge`** content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457006/6309) that would generate (automatically on `git checkout`) the private file out of an external value file and a versioned template file.

For a collection of files, you would use a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), which would register the public files in a nested folder as a nested git repo of the main parent one: the private repo.