# How to protect some files on gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to put some confidential code on my companies’ Gitlab . But I will like that not even Gitlab Admin does not have access to some of my project files.

My question is does gitlab have some automatic and clean way to cipher some files / folders on a git project?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: For what purpose you put confidential code to a company's repository? Is it better to create private repository outside of the company?

Comment: I don't think that gitlab has a feature like that, but git itself has some hooks that allow you to process specific files on stage (`git add`)/checkout. These "hooks" are called clean/smudge filters.
See this answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457006/86072

Comment: @404pio : It's code for my company :) But not for all members (me and my coworkers have no trust on the IT who manage the gitlab... ). But my manager wan't us to only use one gitlab => the company one...

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, that looks Good ! Many Thanks !

Comment: @MatthB you can encode your files with public key, and share private key to your colege to decrypt files. You can create repository on your file, and expose it to your local network so your college can read. You have plenty of options. But no dedicated sollution in gitlab.