# Can I load one .gitconfig file from another?

Tags: git, git-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to include a file in your .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig)

With bash and zsh I can source subfiles in order to better organize my config.

Can I do something similar with `.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(March 2012) It looks like this is finally going to be possible soon -- git 1.7.10 is going to support this syntax in `.gitconfig`:

```
[include]
    path = /path/to/file
```

See [here](https://github.com/gitster/git/commit/9b25a0b52e09400719366f0a33d0d0da98bbf7b0) for a detailed description of the git change and its edge cases.

By the way, a couple of subtleties worth pointing out:

1. Path expansion, e.g. `~` or `$HOME`, does not appear to be supported.
2. If a relative path is specified, then it is relative to the .gitconfig file that has the `[include]` statement.  This works correctly even across chained includes -- e.g. `~/.gitconfig` can have:

   ```
   [include]
       path = subdir/gitconfig
   ```

   and `subdir/gitconfig` can have:

   ```
   [include]
       path = nested_subdir/gitconfig
   ```

   ... which will cause `subdir/nested_subdir/gitconfig` to be loaded.
3. If git can't find the target file, it silently ignores the error.  This appears to be by design.

Answer (score 5):

(March 2012): As mentioned in [Mike Morearty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179675/mike-morearty)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733336/6309) (which I upvoted), git 1.7.10+ will support this feature.

---

Original answer (October 2010):

Currently, no.

As I mentioned in [Is it possible to include a file in your `.gitconfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig), you already have 3 separate gitconfig for you to get your settings organized:

```
$GIT_DIR/config
```

> Repository specific configuration file. (The filename is of course relative to the repository root, not the working directory.)

```
~/.gitconfig
```

> User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.

```
$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
```

> System-wide configuration file

Config File inclusion was discussed in May 2010, and a [first patch was written](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2010/5/6/29891) by Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason, but I don't see this patch in one of the latest "[what's cooking in Git](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/159023)".