# Can gitconfig options be set conditionally?

Tags: git, git-config

Via Github I use the same set of "dot files" on several different computers and servers. On the Macs and Linux boxes under my direct control I have Sublime Text 2 installed and set up as my git merge and commit editor of choice. However, on remote (i.e., not under my direct control) servers I would select to use vim.

I would rather not create and maintain a second `.gitconfig` for those remote servers. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
[core]
    if [[ $IS_REMOTE -eq 1 ]]; then
        editor = "vim"
    else
        editor = "subl -n -w"
    fi
```

where I've somehow set $IS_REMOTE based on the hostname?

Comment: Why not just use a script file as "editor" value in which you check that? (Because no, git config is not conditional)

Comment: Conditional include gitconfig starts to be possible with Git 2.13. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it isn't possible to test an environment variable and programmatically alter the .gitconfig, and since scripting the creation of two .gitconfig files feels like more work than I really want to put forth, I'm just going to create two .gitconfig files. On those machines where I can setup Sublime Text 2 as my editor, and have control over the merge tool and diff tool, I'll use the "primary" gitconfig as the target of my symbolic link. On those machines where I don't have ST2 as an option, I'll use the "secondary" gitconfig file.

Comment: You can split out common config in a 3rd file, and include it in the others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030540/can-i-load-one-gitconfig-file-from-another

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as the best answer. It just shows your preference, which is influenced by your giving up on the actual objective. If someone still wants to do this, the best answer is one of the above.

Answer (score 32):

You can conditionally include another Git config file based on your Git directory or branch in Git 2.13 and later.

Put your default configuration in file `~/.gitconfig` as usual. At the end, conditionally include another configuration file:

```
[user]
    email = john@personal.com
    name = John McGehee

# All work Git repositories are in a subdirectory of ~/work.
# All other Git repositories are outside ~/work.
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = .gitconfig.work
```

Then, in `~/.gitconfig.work` add or override configuration values you want when using a repository located in `~/work` or any subdirectory thereof:

```
[user]
    email = john@work.com
```

You can observe the difference by changing to a Git directory under `~/work`, and running:

```
git config user.email
```

Try the same command in a Git directory that is not under `~/work`.

Comment: Note that the `[includeIf]` section must come *below* any sections, (e.g. `[user]`), whose values you want to override. (This might be obvious to everyone but me, however, since it tripped me up, I thought I'd share.)

Answer (score 21):

No, Git config does not support checks or conditional statements. But your underlying shell probably does, so you can use something like:

```
[core]
    editor = "if [[ $IS_REMOTE -eq 1 ]]; then ED='vim'; else ED='subl -n -w'; fi; $ED"
```

If you need to do something more complicated than that, you could just throw the shell code into a script, of course, like

```
[core]
    editor = "my_edi_script.sh"
```

with `my_edit_script.sh` containing something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $IS_REMOTE -eq 1 ]]; then
    ED="vim"
else
    ED="subl -n -w"
fi

$ED some argument or other
```

**Edit**: The `my_edit_script.sh` would have to be in the $PATH, of course :)

Comment: In addition to the editor setting, the merge tool and diff tool settings will also change for the remote machines. I think the solution in the end is to have two .gitconfig files.

Comment: Tried both of your methods, but they didn't work for the credential.helper setting. I got errors like: "git: 'credential-my_credential_script.sh' is not a git command."

Comment: ```[alias]NEWLINEHEREb = "!if [ -z $1 ]; then git branch -av; else git branch $1 $2 $3 $4; fi"``` is there some way to make this work without the syntax error showing up?

Comment: I tried your solution, the first one works, the second one ('my_edit_script.sh') failed, with messages like: `command not found: ED`

Comment: @ChrisZZ in the script, the last line should be `$ED`, which means invoke the command

Comment: correction: the last line should be `$ED "$@" # invoke the editor`

Answer (score 15):

The `[include]` section learned by git-config in [v1.7.9](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=9b25a0b52e09400719366f0a33d0d0da98bbf7b0) gets you most of the way there.

While it doesn't let you write runtime conditionals, it *does* give you a framework for refactoring your `~/.gitconfig` into several parts: the *shared* section, and the *env-specific* sections. After that, you can symlink something like `~/.gitconfig.local` to the relevant env-specific config file, and include `~/.gitconfig.local` from `~/.gitconfig`.

The symlinking part can be scripted and done automatically as part of your dotfiles' init script.

From the command line, that include path can be added via:

```sh
git config --global include.path '~/.gitconfig.local'
```

I use the quotes above specifically to prevent the shell from expanding `~` to an absolute path.

That adds the following section to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```ini
[include]
    path = ~/.gitconfig.local
```

Here's a snippet from the [git-scm book](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) showing the general format:

```ini
[include]
    path = /path/to/foo.inc ; include by absolute path
    path = foo ; expand "foo" relative to the current file
    path = ~/foo ; expand "foo" in your $HOME directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this, but instead of maintaining your `.gitconfig` file, how about maintaining a script that generates your `.gitconfig` file? That way you can do whatever you want, based not only on variables but also on the output of commands and whatever...

like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
    IS_REMOTE=
else
    case "$1" in
        remote)
            IS_REMOTE=1
            ;;
        local)
            IS_REMOTE=
            ;;
        *)
            echo "value $1 not supported" >&2
            ;;
    esac
fi

# config for both remote and local
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global alias.top '!pwd -L'

# config for remote
if [ "$IS_REMOTE" ]
then
    git config --global core.editor vim
    ...
else
    git config --global core.editor 'subl -n -w'
    ...
fi
```

So, if you call the script without parameters, or with the 'local' parameter, it will generate some configuration to your `.gitconfig` file, while if you pass the 'remote' parameter to it, it will generate some others.

Comment: While I am attracted to the idea of using a scrip to generate the .gitconfig file, for as often as I'd have to make updates to two .gitconfig variations, I think it's more work that I am willing to put forth.

Comment: This would work technically, but it's not the right approach. The answers above are much simpler and neater.

Answer (score 1):

Since Git v2.31 you could also set environment variables in your `.bashrc` or whatever, e.g. on WSL2 I use the following to configure git to used the cached git https credentials from Windows:

```
export GIT_CONFIG_COUNT=2 \
GIT_CONFIG_KEY_0="credential.helper" GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_0="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager-core.exe" \
GIT_CONFIG_KEY_1="credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath" GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_1="true"
```

Credit to VonC for pointing this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963666/9189668

Answer (score -1):

not exactly an answer to your question but interesting for related usecases:
since git [1.8.5](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt) you are allowed to use urlmatch syntax

see 
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config
for details

config entries regarding remotes are the only one that can be defined conditionally like

`[http "https://localhost" ]
  sslVerify = false`

^ will switch of ssl verification for localhost "remotes" only