# Can git config file use if else statement?

Tags: git, git-config

In Git `1.7.?`, `push.default` has value : nothing, matching, tracking ...

In Git `1.8.?`, `push.default` has value : nothing, upstream, simple ...

I custom my `.gitconfig` file :

```
[push]
    default = simple
```

and this will not work in Git 1.7, so I want to to check the `git version` and choose which push.default value to use.

There is a similar question: [Can gitconfig options be set conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754762/can-gitconfig-options-be-set-conditionally)

the answer is use script, is there any other better way?

---

And I use `git --version`, and output this format:

```
git version 1.8.1.5
```

Is there a way to check the version?

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754762/can-gitconfig-options-be-set-conditionally

Comment: @TomRon , I have already metioned this question in my question, and I want to know if have a better way.

Comment: and I want to know, to this condition, is there a simple way to check the git version?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do this as a git config file is just a dumb text file. If you only have two different configs, it will work out a lot easier for you to just have two different config files and use the correct one on each machine.