# Can I set default user.name on http basis?

Tags: git, configuration

It is possible (via `git config --global`) to use e.g. custom proxy settings for certain addresses like:

```
[http "https://github.com/"]
    proxy = http://myproxy.com:80
```

and you can use custom `user.name` per repository with

```
[user]
    name = John
```

but is it possible to combine these two to have a default user.name for a particular address?

I tried the command

```
git config --global http."https://foo.bar/".user.name test
```

but it creates an invalid setting with the `user` being part of the url.

> ```
> [http "https://foo.bar/.user"]
>    name = test
> ```

---

I'd like to have such a default setting because I don't want to remember to specify the `--proxy` switch each time I'm cloning a repository and I have a couple of different sources.

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly with the standard git config. However you can use some scripts to accomplish this. If you are using linux you can head to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754762/can-gitconfig-options-be-set-conditionally?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Git only supports conditional includes, but thats directory based. You can look it up [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes). This would mean that only the initial clone is manual and after that you can set the correct password for that repository.

Tip: I would suggest SSH keys, this way you don't have to log in and only have to add the ssh key to your account once.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a [PAC file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) for your proxy.