GitHub uses my personal account when pushing even though the repo is private and solely my work github account has rights
If I clone using my personal account, it doesn't work. It says it can't find the repo. Makes sense, the repo is private and my personal account is not in it.
So I use:
git clone https://<token>@github.com/.../....git with a token I generated on my work github account.
This works.
Now if I make a modification and push (git add ., git commit -s -m "something", git push), it works, but on the repo, it shows up as if my personal account had made the pushes even though this account does not even belong to the repo. I insist, the token I use is not linked to that personal account.
I'm a bit confused as to what I should do. I think the git credential manager messes things up but I'm not sure how. Also, how does it even work since I shouldn't even have the "rights" to push in that repo with my personal account? Is the token used to bypass security and then what is displayed not even "controlled"? By this I mean does GitHub allow the push event thanks to the token but the commit itself contains author information from the local Git configuration that may not be matching??

The reason you're confused is that you are confusing who pushed with who authored the commit. In other words, you are confusing the question of your authentication with GitHub (the right of the user of this computer to push to this repo) with your identity in Git (whom Git reports as the author of the commit).

Yes I was confused, I had forgotten Git is in fact NOT GitHub. Thanks.

Another way to look at it is to remember that Git doesn't do any sort of authentication.

I would have preferred to comment but I don't have enough reputation
Not sure of my answer but a few hints that might help to understand.
When you commit, Github use 2 information:

Authentication: This is handled by the token you use. The token is associated with your work GitHub account, which has the necessary permissions to push to the repository.

Commit Author Information: This is determined by the configuration of your local Git environment. It uses the name and email address configured in your Git settings.


It seems that your local Git configuration is using the email address associated with your personal GitHub account.
You can check your Git configuration with:
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email

Depends on the result you can update it:
git config --global user.name "Right Name"
git config --global user.email "right-email@example.com"

But if you don't want to change your global configuration, you can set the author information for one repositories:
cd path/to/your/repository
git config user.name "Right Name"
git config user.email "right-email@example.com"


Good answer! But the OP has already pushed some commits with personal commit info so he needs to fix these commits. Any idea how?

I fixed the problematic commit already! (git reset --hard commit_number and git push --force)

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows instead of changing author config for only one repo, you could do it for all repos and futur repos contained in a specific folder using conditional include https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184292/717372 It's a better solution if you know that you will have multiple repositories for your work (because you fix the issue once and for all).
