# is there any way how to tell git to ignore certain lines of a file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to put my .bashrc .gitconfig and other useful configs on to github (because there are some valuable pieces of code I want to share ) but the thing is I don't want to share certain "valuable informations about me",

so is there any way around to tell git to ignore certain patern or line of a file (for instance in .gitignore? )

*note: I figure how to do my bashrc sharing ( I will keep in bashrc public things and move private to bashprofile that I wont share)  but I'm kinda wondering how to share my gitconfig (there are some pretty good aliases)*

thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can git ignore a specific line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is conceivable to do something of the sort with `gitattributes` and the `smudge` and `clean` filters but it would be messy and probably rather fragile.  My method is simply to put things I don't want public in a non-shared `~/.bashrc.local` file and source that file inside from the shared `.bashrc`, e.g.

```
if [ -r ~/.bashrc.local ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc.local
fi
```

This also allows me to maintain system/machine-specific configs without screwing up my global `.bashrc`.

Comment: This is the setup I also use. You can then store them locally (or in a private git repo somewhere) for replication elsewhere.

Comment: nice solution, but what about files like .gitconfig, I have there lot of aliases, and I was googling for something like ".gitaliases" but it seems like git isn't suporting anything like it,

Comment: basicly I want to just push my [alias] section on github from .gitconfig, and keep my private info inside [user] section hidden.. so can I split it up somehow?  ...but want to keep those setings inside .gitignore global, only solution I fond is for using different settings inside local repositories

Comment: It doesn't seem like `.gitconfig` supports including from external sources.  Maybe this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig) can give you some ideas.  One of the answers mentions using gpg in the smudge/clean filters, but if you don't need that you could come up with some sed/cat filter to extract / concatenate a whole section, which shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: jw013 your last link is weary  help full, clicking answered because of that.

Answer (score 2):

*so just for correct closing of this question:*

the solutions answered here and in comments worked for my problem (split .bashrc) but for the original question :

> is there any way how to tell git to ignore certain lines of a file?

there is no easy way

Comment: This is definitely not correct closing the question: the answer is *accept*ed but it works around the main answer. This makes it harder to ask/find answer for The Original Question: doing it without outsourcing

Comment: I suggest altering this question to a .bashrc or .bashrc-and-likes -specific one. That will make it a perfect Q+A pair, without confusing those who need to find real "line-level" solution

Comment: Additionally, I'd ask the original question (mentioning this one to avoid confusion and duplicate answering) separately. The fact that it will probably remain unanswered is *acceptable* (by the way, never say never, maybe Git 2.0 will support it).

Comment: Actually, there is a way, just as jw013 said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, (which is different from the particular problem you wanted to solve), check out:

[How to tell git to ignore individual lines, i.e. gitignore for specific lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969).