# Gitignore individual lines, sed issue

Tags: git, sed, gitignore

I'm trying to ignore a line from commit, I've found this question [Gitignore single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of), and everything works fine if I do:

```
git config --global filter.gitignore.clean "sed '/#gitignore$/'d"
```

and annotate code with:

```
System.out.println("SimpleLineCode"); #gitignore
```

But I would like to do ignore with this tag `//gitignore` (because I use Java), so I've wrote:

```
git config --global filter.gitignore.clean "sed '///gitignore$/'d"
```

Of course it does not work, and do not know how to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '/' for the Java comment conflicts with the '/' separator of sed. You can escape the / of the comment ("`sed '/\/\/gitignore$/'d`"). Or use a different separator for sed (which would be more readable). "`sed '_//gitignore$_'d`"