# Git diff - ignore specific texts per file type

Tags: git, diff, atlassian-sourcetree, git-config

What I am trying to do is to have git ignore specific pieces of text per file type, and store those settings so can be used through out a project.

The issue is that my IDE adds specific lines/text on files, that I would like Git to ignore and not count as changes. For example:

for .xml files, ignore text like this: `<modified>2019-01-01</modified>`.

for .txt files, ignore text like this: `"# last comment by" and "sequence:"`

for .properties files, ignore text like this: `"some text to ignore"`

etc etc

So, using the examples above, if the only change to an .xml file is the `<modified>` tag data, git should not consider this as a modified file.

What I would like to do is store those settings in a config file so that can be used though out the project. I am currently using SourceTree so if there is a SourceTree specific solution it would be nice to use but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell git to ignore individual lines, i.e. gitignore for specific lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of) or of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line (better)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line)