# gitignore filter - how to add a remote configuration?

Tags: git

I would like to add a gitignore filter for a specific lines of the code. Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of).
It requires calling appropriate `git config` command. When some other user clones that repo the filtering doesn't work unless `git config`command is called. I need a solution where after cloning a repository filtering works without any additional actions. How to solve that problem ?

Comment: Tell your users to use a script that you write, that runs `git clone` followed by the appropriate `git config`. They should run this script *and not run `git clone` at all*. That's the only way to make it work with a single command. Note that **Git will never, on its own, run scripts it just downloaded** as **this would be a horrible security hole**.

Answer (score 0):

You need *git hooks*. Git hooks are scripts that Git executes before or after events.

The *post-checkout* hook also runs on `git-clone` (when run *without* `--no-checkout`).

> It is also run after git-clone, unless the --no-checkout (-n) option is used. The first parameter given to the hook is the null-ref, the second the ref of the new HEAD and the flag is always 1.

[hooks-documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout)

Comment: I need a pre-commit hook which ignores a particular lines of the code but hooks are not pushed to the repository. It looks like it doesn't solve my problem,

Comment: post-checkout: "Run when a checkout is called after updating the worktree or after git clone. It is mainly used to verify conditions, display differences, and configure the environment if necessary." Now you an write your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of) in the git-hook...