# How to tell git to ignore changes to a commited file?

Tags: git

I have a default config file in my git repo. I changed some of the configurations that's only meant for me. There's also a password field so I don't want to commit it. Without removing the file can I tell git to ignore the config file?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally. -- run `git update-index --assume-unchanged <config filename>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319479/can-i-git-commit-a-file-and-ignore-its-content-changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Comment: Don't trust anyone who suggests to use `--assume-unchanged` for this purpose. Use `--skip-worktree` instead. [This is the correct answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/6868543)

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244970/5827913) that might help you ignore specific lines.

That being said, a very common pattern is to have a tracked sample file that everyone copies to their own environment and add the actual settings file to `gitignore`.

For example you could have a `.config.example` file with just sample values and add that to your repo, and a `.config` with the sensitive values, that is private to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you develop a configuration system similar to this:

`env` (default/global config file)

`env.local` (local config file included in .gitignore)

Where the parameters defined in `env.local` have priority over those defined in `env`.

However you can review [this](https://gist.github.com/koudaiii/54e3c438a85a52c7c368) tutorial on how to ignore lines. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of) other question.