# Ignore specific file line during pull/push git operations

Tags: git, scripting, hook, githooks, pre-commit

I'm here to ask a question related to topic discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574486/10170926).
In this example @Mike shown how to add pre-hook script in order to ignore
Java code lines with comment "//no commit".

I've done the same thing in order to ignore
.xml file lines: in particular I mark each line with this comment "<!--no commit-->" and used a pre-commit script that doesn't allow to commit if a change is made on line marked with specific comment.

Now, I want to ask to the community if it is possible to implement a pre-commit hook script that allow me to do the commit without the change made on lines marked with comment and without resetting them.