# How can I have part of a code never to be commited in git

Tags: javascript, git, github, gitignore

Let's suppose we have a file which we are heavily changing. So in case of trial-and-error, we write something for testing. which we don't want to send to commit or even get noticed by git.  like

```js
function testThis(){
   console.log('helloworld');
}
```

I write this function, this is part of a very big file. during staging this change will be considered. Since there are many changes like this in a file. So it is possible that during hand picking which change to stage, this change might get staged by mistake.

So my question is: **Is there any wrapper or something that is particular to git, in which if I wrap this code, then this change will not even be considered for staging**, let alone for committing. something like

```
<.gitignore>
function testThis(){
   console.log('helloworld');
}
</.gitignore>
```

Comment: Why not just put this code into a separate file, link the files and do the requisite testing, and `.gitignore` the test file? Although you probably should be writing and committing formal tests of your codebase to your repository anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line) or [How to tell git to ignore individual lines, i.e. gitignore for specific lines of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244969/how-to-tell-git-to-ignore-individual-lines-i-e-gitignore-for-specific-lines-of)

Comment: @esqew. i ended up doing just that.

Comment: @NullDev yes these looks promising, but there are risks doing it. also it looks like it will increase work load instead of decreasing it because i will have to gitattribute each individual line for that

Answer (score 1):

gitignore allows you to ignore patterns/files. As a result, a very neat solution is to separate all the code you are developing for your own experiments and gitignore it. Let's suppose that your site is using **myfile.js**. However, somewhere you could implement a logic that does this:

- if **myfile-custom.js** exists, then it uses it
- otherwise it uses **myfile.js**
- gitignore **myfile-custom.js**

This would mean that you could create a copy of **myfile.js** by the name of **myfile-custom.js**, starting with the exact content of **myfile.js** and doing your changes. If the logic above is implemented, then your local will pick up your custom code and use that, while you will never be in danger of committing it.

Comment: i ended up doing just that.

Answer (score 1):

You may choose a special keyword, which you can reject in a pre-commit hook.

For example : I use the word `dontcommit`, and I have the following section in my `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file :

```bash
dontcommit=0

# list files that are staged:
for file in $(git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD --diff-filter=ACMR); do
    # look for the forbidden keyword in their content:
    if git grep --cached -q -i dontcommit "$file"; then
        dontcommit=1
        git grep --cached -n -i dontcommit "$file"
    fi
done

if test $dontcommit -eq 1; then
    echo " *** aborting commit, 'dontcommit' tag found in staged files"
    exit 1
fi
```

That way, when I add code and know that I shouldn't commit it at all, I just a add `// dontcommit` next to it :

```
function testThis(){
   // dontcommit
   console.log('helloworld');
}
```

To stage the other parts of such a file, I can still use partial staging with `git add -p` or a graphical tool to add only specific chunks (for example: the built in `git gui` utility)

Comment: does this method covers a block ?. i myself use git feature in vscode, i always go throgh each changes and file manually to stage it. bit tedious but worth it.