# Hiding GitHub token in .gitconfig

Tags: linux, git, bash, github

I would like to store all of my dotfiles on GitHub, including .gitconfig which requires me to hide the GitHub token in the .gitconfig.

To do so I have a ".gitconfig-hidden-token" file which is the file I intend to edit and put under git that hides the token:

```
...
[github]
user = giuliop
token = --hidden--
...
```

And a shell script which I need to launch if I modify the ".gitconfig-hidden-token" file  to create the ".gitconfig" file:

```
cp .gitconfig .gitconfig.backup
sed 's/--hidden--/123456789/' .gitconfig-hidden-token > .gitconfig
```

The drawback is the need to manually launch the script everytime I modidy the file. Is there a better, fully automated way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add your .gitconfig with `git add -N`.

Then `git add -p` it, edit the hunk, replace the token with anything, and push that. No need for an extra file this way.

Addendum: on additional modifications of your file, use `git add -p` again, and edit the hunk so that your initial manipulation not be overwritten.

Comment: what happens if I edit the file subsequently and `git add` it forgetting the `-p`? I suppose the token would be published then

Comment: @gws: indeed, but then you can (and should probably) use `git diff --cached` before committing, and in case of error, just `git reset` the file as well.

Comment: I think the correct approach is to use `include` per the answer of @ddopson

Answer (score 40):

I just fixed this up for myself.  The "proper" way to solve the issue is to split your gitconfig into two files, a public one with the alias/config/etc, and a private file that keeps your username and secrets. Like so...

From https://github.com/ddopson/dotfiles ...

**.gitconfig:**

```
[include]
  # For username / creds / etc
  path = ~/.gitconfig.local

[alias]
  ...
```

**.gitconfig.local:**

```
[user]
  user = ddopson
  name = Dave Dopson
  email = ddopson@gmail.com
  token = a123uber456secret789ceprivate000key78

[credential]
  helper = osxkeychain
```

**.gitignore:**

```
/.gitconfig.local
```

Comment: If you keep your `.gitconfig.local` file in the same development directory as your dotfiles git repository, don't forget to add `.gitconfig.local` to your project's `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 3):

You can now include another file in your gitconfig. You could put your github section in that extra file. See this question: [Is it possible to include a file in your .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig)

Answer (score 1):

I made a script to update my dotfiles repo, it also redacts sensitive information such as my github token. I don't think the github token is used by GitHub anymore though, but correct me if I'm wrong.

You can view my script [here](https://github.com/dideler/dotfiles/blob/master/update.sh#L22).