# Understanding Meld 3 way merge with Git

Tags: git, repository, meld, 3-way-merge

My boss set up our new Git repository, one on our Windows server and one on our Linux Server.

I was asked to resolve our conflicts so I chose to use Meld.

When I run the first file it opens 3 windows;

- shipping.php.local.####,
- shipping.php
- shipping.remote.####

I have read the docs and help but I'm having trouble understanding. From what I can see, the *shipping.remote* has the changes I made to the files on the Linux box that I want to keep. *shipping.local* are the files from the Windows server and the *shipping.php* is the file that will result from the merge.

So if I just take the code from the *shipping.remote*, move it to the middle file(shipping.php) and save it, I will have the updated file I want on the Git repository on the Linux box?

I hope I'm explaining correctly, I just don't want to mess something up.

Comment: remote/local change here since you are applying your commits on the origin(base) so that origin become local and yours are remote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You understand correctly what are the files you see. But if you merge in a way you described (incorporate changes from remote to base), you will loose changes from local. In fact, you have to merge both local and remote into base. You could use Changes | Merge all non-conflicting and then resolve each conflict by hand.

Comment: Got it, I got all three to match up with the changes I want from each. Thank you

Comment: Actually it is enough, that the middle on has all the changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133290/git-merging-using-meld