# How do I use Meld as a merge tool with Sourcetree on Windows?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, meld

I have the following in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[user]
    name = myname
    email = myname@gmail.com
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
[diff]
        tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
        cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe"
        prompt = false
[merge]
        tool = meld

[mergetool "meld"]
        cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe"
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe $PWD/$LOCAL $PWD/$BASE $PWD/$REMOTE"
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
```

And in Sourcetree, I have the following settings:

[image]

However, when I right-clicked a file on Sourcetree to do an external diff, I was able to open Meld, but the contents of the file were not displayed at all.

[image]

What have I done wrong in the settings?

Answer (score 48):

I feel the existing answers slightly missed the point. Here is my own dog food:

[image]

Arguments Detail:

```
Diff:  $LOCAL $REMOTE
Merge: $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE --auto-merge --output=$MERGED
```

For `External Diff`, you need to remove $BASE from your argument list.

For 3-way merging, you need to click on the `External Merge Tool` option instead, which will only be available if there are any unsolved conflicts.

[image: Context menu of External Merge Tool]

If you are not restricted to *Sourcetree + Meld*, I reckon the [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) + [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) suite could be a good open-sourced alternative also.

Comment: BTW, according to others, the Meld "3-way comparison" is not a actual 3-way merging, because a 3-way merging requires 4 windows: base, local, remote, merged

Comment: You should paste the args into your answer. It isn't clear if there is more arguments in the latter example. Such as:
`$LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE --auto-merge --output=$MERGED`

Comment: So, should the arguments be those in the screenshot or in the text?

Comment: @Andrew The one in the text is more detailed.

Answer (score 24):

The actual setting to use here in order to have a real 3-way merge, with read only THEIRS and MINE tabs is this:

```
$LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE --auto-merge --output=$MERGED
```

Note the `=` after `--output`.

I've finally got this command right by digging in comments on the second answer to  this question [Git merging using Meld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133290/git-merging-using-meld).

Answer (score 19):

For **OS X** it looks like this:

- Diff Command: `/Applications/Meld.app/Contents/MacOS/meld`.

  - Arguments: `$LOCAL $REMOTE`
- Merge Command: `/Applications/Meld.app/Contents/MacOS/meld`.

  - Arguments: `$LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE --auto-merge --output=$MERGED`

P.S.
you might have to configure the order of $local and $ remote in meld prefrences as well..

To use it from command line you have to install it via **brew**:
`brew install meld`

[image: Sourcetree preferences pane]

Comment: Using a prebuilt Meld.app from [https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/]

I needed to set the Diff Command to:
 `/Applications/Meld.app/Contents/MacOS/meld`

Comment: Didn't work out of the box for me. needed to use:
`$LOCAL $REMOTE` for diff arguments.

Comment: I had to do `brew tap homebrew/cask`, and then `brew cask install meld` in order to install it on OSX. Testing it now, thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `@LOCAL` and `@REMOTE` ?? Shouldn't it be `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` ??

Comment: if install via brew,the diff and merge command i used is : /usr/local/bin/meld on my osx,this can work

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the location of meld.exe to your PATH (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld), and then in the *Diff Command*, just enter meld instead of the full path. See the gist *[How to use meld with Sourcetree on Windows](https://gist.github.com/chinhodado/6fc37def3e12ea09f785)*.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify the PATH environment variable, you can use the DOS-compatible short names:

```
C:\Progra~1 = C:\Program Files
C:\Progra~2 = C:\Program Files (x86)
```

That avoids the trouble-causing spaces in the path and plays nice with Sourcetree. It's hackish, but it works. You can then use something like this as the path to Meld:

```
C:\Progra~1\Meld\meld.exe
```

It may not be guaranteed that Progra~1 maps to the 64-bit directory, so you might need to experiment with which one maps to which.