# Can SourceTree show diff side-by-side

Tags: git, diff, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I started to use SourchTree recently.

The default format of the diff is to use "-" or "+" to show changes.
I like to have 2 files side-by-side and show the change line to line.

However, I cannot find the option to change the format. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see any "side-by-side diff" button on the diff view, then a good workaround is to setup a difftool in your SourceTree.

See for instance "[How to use Meld as a merge tool with SourceTree on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37432812/6309)".

Using an external diff tool (supporting natively a side-by-side view) is more reliable than the native tool options here.

Comment: Do you see any "side-by-side diff" button?

Comment: @FuscaSoftware No, I still do not see a side-by-side diff option in 2023, with SourceTree version 3.4.11.

Answer (score 16):

No, I really hope to see that feature in some of the future releases.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to view both **side-by-side** as well as **inline** both at the same time by using a tool in Source Tree.

1. Download and install [Perforce Merge/Diff tool](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge)
2. Now open your repo in source tree and click on **3 dots within circle** icons on the top right corner in UI now and click on **External Diff** a new window will open which will show all the changes **side-by-side** as well **inline** (Worked for me in Mac Book Pro M1)!!

For more info can refer to corresponding Jira ticket for Source Tree: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1296

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a solution as it basically means use something other than SourceTree. I would like to do this yet where I work we are very restricted in what we can download and install and have only been given SourceTree or command-line git. This problem is something I'm sure many face in today's somewhat paranoid cyber-security world.

Comment: Thanks but, sometimes Sourcetree can't recognize which external diff tool to use for the purpose. To tell more robustly Sourcetree: 
On the main window right click => Custom Actions => Edit => Diff (in the header menu) => Visual Diff Tool
Now you can select the tool you downloaded before.

* Sourcetree: Version 4.2.1 (248)