# GIT Meld how to keep both changes during merge?

Tags: git, meld

I am using Meld in Sourcetree to resolve conflicts. 
The issue that is faced is that i must select local or remote changes and i can't keep both changes. Any idea if this is possible in Meld?

Comment: it might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133290/which-version-of-the-git-file-will-be-finally-used-local-base-or-remote

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can choose one side and then add the other by pressing CTRL on your keyboard. It'll prompt you if you want to add above or below your previous added change.

> In addition to directly editing text files, Meld gives you tools to move, copy or delete individual differences between files. The bar between two files not only shows you what parts of the two files correspond, but also lets you selectively merge or delete differing changes by clicking the arrow or cross icons next to the start of each change.
>
> The default action is replace. This action replaces the contents of the corresponding change with the current change.
>
> Hold down the Shift key to change the current action to delete. This action deletes the current change.
>
> Hold down the Ctrl key to change the current action to insert. This action inserts the current change above or below (as selected) the corresponding change.

For more infos: http://meldmerge.org/help/file-changes.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Short answers with external urls are not considered high quality as the external link can break or its contents can change. Please ensure the key details are included in your answer.