# Merge two branches by using code from both of them

Tags: git, git-merge, meld

I have two branches master and i1:

Branch `master`:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    std::cout << "1";
    std::cout << "3";
    std::cout << "5";
    return 0;
}
```

Branch `i1`:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    std::cout << "1";
    std::cout << "2";
    std::cout << "4";
    std::cout << "6";
    return 0;
}
```

Got conflict while merging `i1` to `master` :

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    std::cout << "1";
<<<<<<< HEAD
    std::cout << "2";
    std::cout << "4";
    std::cout << "6";
=======
    std::cout << "3";
    std::cout << "5";
>>>>>>> master
    return 0;
}
```

I do merge with Meld:

[image]

Meld offers only to choose `master` or `i1`. How to have both of them in result?

Comment: Not have used Meld yet but what about that answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812907/git-meld-how-to-keep-both-changes-during-merge

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Meld for this. Any text editor will do. You have the conflict expressed in your file:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    std::cout << "1";
<<<<<<< HEAD
    std::cout << "2";
    std::cout << "4";
    std::cout << "6";
=======
    std::cout << "3";
    std::cout << "5";
>>>>>>> master
    return 0;
}
```

Just eliminate the merge conflict markers and arrange the code in the order you want it:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    std::cout << "1";
    std::cout << "2";
    std::cout << "3";
    std::cout << "4";
    std::cout << "5";
    std::cout << "6";
    return 0;
}
```

Save, add, and commit.