# Is it possible to push content from the .git/config file?

Tags: git

I have some settings in my `.git/config` file. Now I would like my build server to pick up these configurations when it clones the job. But there is no `.git/config` file in the cloned repo on the buildserver.

How do I push changes from my local .git/config file to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You don't directly: [config are never pushed, for security reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548056/6309).

You could version the part of the config you need, and make sure to manually add a git config directive in the server repo which would **include** your versioned config file.
See "[Is it possible to include a file in your .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733277/6309)".

```
[include]
    path = /path/to/file
```

Then, the repo on the server would pick up any config modification you are pushing (since you would be pushing a versioned file, which would be included in the config of the remote repo).

Comment: Ok so configs in .git/config does not have corresponding configs valid for .gitattributes (which is committed/pushed)? Then the configs could be read from that file instead.

Comment: @u123 yes, `.git/config` does not have corresponding configs valid for `.gitattributes`. You need to manage your config in a separate file (at least separate from `.gitattributes`)