# What is the syntax for specifying Windows paths in .gitconfig?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, path

I'm trying to use the [`include.path` config described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig), but I can't seem to find the correct path syntax on Windows.

My current .gitconfig:

```
[include]
    path = 'D:\Scott\Shared\config\common.gitconfig'
```

But git complains: `fatal: bad config file line 2 in C:\Users\Scott/.gitconfig`

What's the proper way to escape paths for Windows? Note: I'm using git from Powershell and not git bash.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, figured this out. The trick is:

1. Surround in double-quotes
2. Convert backslashes to forward slashes.
3. Begin with drive letter + colon for absolute paths

So the correct version of the above is:

```
[include]
    path = "D:/Scott/Shared/config/common.gitconfig"
```

Comment: Can't get it to work on Win 7, git version 1.9.5.  
If I run `git config --global -l` I get `include.path=c:/common/git/commonConfig`.  None of the content of commonConfig appears to be read in.

Comment: This still works for me. Note that I don't see configs from `git config --global -l`, but they are available for other git commands (difftool, aliases, etc.). Windows 8.1 and `git --version`: 1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: Scott W.: Yes, I finally figured out that `git config --global -l` just seems to read the config file w/o expanding include.path, while other git commands work as expected.  Unfortunate that the simple way to view config isn't available...

Comment: @Number8 Specifying a config file (like `--global`) prevents expanding the `include.path`, but there is `--includes`, so you can use `git config --global --includes -l` or simply `git config -l` outside any repository to see both global and system config.

Comment: use double quotes and backslashes before spaces: git config --something "c:/my\ windows \path/"

Answer (score -1):

Based on output of `pwd` in git bash, I would speculate it is probably

```
/d/Scott/Shared/config/common.gitconfig
```

Comment: Thanks letitbee, though this doesn't seem to work for me. I should mention that I'm using Powershell and not git bash (will update question). I just found a syntax that does work that I've also posted as an answer.

Comment: If only Windows was keen to follow an intuitive approach, sigh... This doesn't work for me either. However the author's self-answer does.

Comment: I would postulate that your speculation is incorrect. :/