# how to use include.path on Windows

Tags: git

`[master +0 ~1 -0]> git --version

git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1`

I found this answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28520596/107037 -- but can't get it to work for me.
In my ~/.gitconfig, I have

```
[user]
name = CB
email = cb@gmail.com
[include]  
path = "c:/common/git/commonConfig"
```

then running

```
> git config --global -l
```

produces

```
user.name=CB
user.email=cb@gmail.com  
include.path=c:/common/git/commonConfig
```

I have tried forward slashes, backslashes, quoting the path, not quoting the path....
The one combination I haven't tried is the one that works, apparently.
Thanks for any hints, this is a really powerful feature for sharing settings across computers.

Comment: Check this http://choorucode.com/2011/06/02/git-config-file-on-windows/

Comment: What on earth does that have to do with my question about include.path?

Comment: Did you try formatting the path based on the link there? Apologies if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: @gran_profaci The URL you're referring is: http://codeyarns.com/2011/06/02/git-config-file-on-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `git config -l` to check whether the include is working as expected, you'll need to ensure that you're also providing the --includes argument, otherwise it doesn't perform the include processing.

The documentation states that it defaults to on, but it doesn't actually seem to be the case on Windows.

```
--[no-]includes
    Respect include.* directives in config files when looking up values. Defaults to on.
```

Comment: That seems to work as desired.  Marked as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use the Unix form, with Cygwin this is

```
/cygdrive/c/common/git/commonConfig
```

With MSYS this should be

```
/c/common/git/commonConfig
```

Comment: Same result: `include.path=/c/common/git/commonConfig`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the file just next to the `.gitconfig` and use:

```
[include]
    path = ~/common.gitconfig
```

I did it the inverse way, including the personal data (email and name) and it works well...

PS: you could even use a relative path from here if you want.

Comment: I want to put the common config file in my skydrive directory, so it is easy to configure git on all computers I use.  I use the same strategy for vim and powershell, and it works very well -- a computer-specific config file with a few local settings, and a way to include the common config file.

Comment: Well, this is confusing.  It appears the include.path is generally working as desired, but not for `git config --global -l` -- that seems to merely read ~\.gitconfig w/o processing the include.  Continuing to experiment, but `path = c:/common/git/commonConfig` seems to be working (my difftool settings are recognized, for example).