# GitConfig backslash problem IntelliJ mergetool and difftool

Tags: git, intellij-idea, mergetool, git-difftool

I currently have in `C:\Users\me\.gitconfig` the following contents

```
[merge]
    tool = intellij
[mergetool "intellij"]
    cmd = cmd.exe //c "\"C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5/bin/idea.bat\" merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\""
    trustExitCode = true
[diff]
    tool = intellij
[difftool "intellij"]
    cmd = cmd.exe //c "\"C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5/bin/idea.bat\" diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
```

and when I do `git difftool` I get

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

In [Git Docs], it is mentioned that

> The following escape sequences (beside \" and \) are recognized: \n
>   for newline character (NL), \t for horizontal tabulation (HT, TAB) and
>   \b for backspace (BS). Other char escape sequences (including octal
>   escape sequences) are invalid.

I also looked at [Syntax for specifying Windows paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28520596/3125070) and tried some combinations:

```
# Escape spaces
Program\\ Files
Program/ Files
Program\ Files

# Backslashes
C:\Program Files\...
# 'C:\Program' is not recognized
```

But none worked, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way woud be to test the unix syntax

```
cmd = "/C/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5/bin/idea.bat"...
```

The other would be to add `C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5/bin` to your `%PATH%`, allowing you to reference the bat file directly.

```
cmd = cmd.exe /c idea.bat ...
```