# Include the git config file under the .git folder

Tags: git, heroku, gitignore

I have a code repo that has multiple remotes, and the remotes were configured locally on my computer.

After pushing the code to origin and having a colleague pull the code, I have to set up the list of remotes again.

Is there a way to include the .git/config file as part of the repo's commits?  If not, would be happy to hear other recommendations too.

FYI, I've tried both adding the include path as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig) as well as adding the !filename line to .gitignore, to no effect.

Thanks ahead for your help/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot include files inside your `.git` repository in the repository itself.  The ability to do so would be a substantial security risk, because it would permit someone to -- for example -- install scripts into your `.git/hooks` directory, or simply corrupt your local repository.  So yeah, that would be a terrible idea.

An easier solution is to include a script in your repository that your colleague can run that will set up the necessary remotes.  That is, create a script called something like `update-remotes`, and have it run a series of `git remote add` commands.  Include that script in your repository as well as instructions for running it.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks larsks.  Follow-up question: our team develops with from multiple OSes, and I don't think a script would work across OSX, Windows, Linux boxes.  Any thoughts on a unified way of doing this?

Comment: Additionally, the idea of adding scripts into a repo which is basically pure code that we would directly push to a server seems foreign to me.  I get the feeling this is something to read further up on, any resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Whereas the idea of adding a script to a repo in order to assist with common setup operations (adding remotes, creating pre-commit hooks, etc) seems perfectly natural to me.  I don't have any references for you; either include a document that describes that manual process people must use to set up the necessary remotes, or you include a script to automate it.  You could produce a script *external* to the repository that would perform the initial clone and set up the remotes. A script containing only `git` commands would run fine on OSX, Windows, and Linux, provided the `git` CLI was available.