# Cross Git repositories config file

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

We have multiple Git repositories (one per project..), and we have configuration files which should stay "synced" across all projects, but should also be in the Git repository, for example - pipelines yaml, and static analysis configuration yaml.

What is the best way to hold those configuration files in a central place? (e.g. central Git repository, symbolic links to remote host?)

Maybe using Bitbucket webhooks with our own custom "agent" is the best option?

Comment: Submodules are the answer. The question is: do you want a monolith repo which tracks the config files with all the projects as submodules, or a separate config repo that gets pulled in as a submodule in each project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9733277/2303202 maybe you could find some solution with use of include

Comment: @pockets - sub modules adds a directory to the tree, which is a problem for us.

Comment: @max630 - this seems to be used only to include gitconfig files..

Comment: As I said in my comment, you have two options with submodules, and I don't see why the former doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your config file in a Git repository, and reference that repository as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) from the other Git repositories.

Notice that whenever you change the shared repository (containing common config files), you have to sync regularly from each of the other Git repositories, e.g.:

```
>git submodule update --remote
```

would pull all latest changes from all the submodules of the repository you launch this command within.

Comment: Git submodule requires that I'll add a directory, and the config files should be in the root directory. Am I wrong? And one more thing is that I won't be able to "push" updates to all Git repos from a central place (not sure if there's a way to do so)

Comment: You could create a submodule in any subdirectory, i.e. `>git submodule add ssh://user@host/bla/bla subdir/sub1` There is no way to to push updates to repositories, each of them needs to be updated.

Comment: Cappas's - I don't want another directory in my root dorectory. Thats a problem and git submodules are only available within directories