# Git - add local config file

Tags: git, configuration

I wish to check in changes that I have made to my local GIT config file and when I tried this command:

`git add .git/config --force`

It errors out with the following message:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .git/config.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: invalid path '.git/config'
error: unable to add '.git/config' to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

Wondering if this is possible, or if this is considered bad practice.
Note: What I am trying to do is check some default diff tools that the entire team needs to use. If this is considered bad practices, how do I go about accomplishing this? (Other settings I might wish to standardize: whitespace, auto conversion of crlf, etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to include a file in your .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add files located under `.git/`
`.git/config` also contains local information, such as the list of remote tracking branches, or remote configuration, and it does not make much sense to share these.

Close enough : you can commit a common config file in your repo, and set up each clone with an `include` directive to include this file :

```
# relative path are relative to the .git/ directory :
git config include.path ../common_config
```

Link to docs : [includes and conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [.gitattributes file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) instead.

Comment: You cant use .gitattributes for many things. As an example, one cant add difftool settings,etc.