# Any exception to use include in .gitconfig?

Tags: linux, git, configuration

Following up on [Is it possible to include a file in your .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig), are there any exceptions to use `include` in the `.gitconfig` file? Why mine is not working?

```bash
$ cat .gitconfig
[include]
    path = /tmp/.gitconfig.id

$ cat /tmp/.gitconfig.id

[user]
        name = Me
        email = my@my.place.com

$ git config --global user.name | wc
      0       0       0

$ git -v
git version 2.39.2

$ uname -rms
Linux 6.1.0-9-amd64 x86_64

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
```

I.e., I found myself can use `include` in the `.gitconfig` for *all* sections *except* `[user]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`--[no-]includes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---no-includes):

> Respect `include.*` directives in config files when looking up values. Defaults to `off` when a specific file is given (e.g., using `--file`, `--global`, etc) and `on` when searching all config files.

I.e. either omit `--global`:

```
git config user.name | wc
```

or add `--includes`:

```
git config --global --includes user.name | wc
```